# Which quests should I take to get an independent New Vegas and happy endings?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

After hours role-playing Fallout New Vegas as a good guy, I got to meet Yes Man and now I am planning on play for an independent New Vegas. I'd like to know which quests I should do from now on cause I also want to get good endings.

This is mostly what I've done so far

- I am vilified for the Legion and Powder Gangers, I killed all of the guys in NCRCF and I haven't meet Caesar yet
- I am idiolized in Goodsprings, Novac and liked in Freeside. I've done most of their quests with good results
- I am a member of Brotherhood of Steel and sided with Elder Macnamara
- I am liked for Boomers and Khans, I told Papa Khan to go and recover their former glory
- NCR idolizes me cause I started with them and did a lot of quests for them, now I got a note from some ambassador telling me he'd like to meet me
- I've done the quest of: Boone, Cass, Rex. I also have ED-E, the ghoul guy from Black Mountain and Lilly with me
- I refused Mr House offer to work for him

So, what now? I am aware Yes Man will give some quests, but before that I'd like to know which "business" I should finish. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which independent NV did you want? Do you want to run it, or House?

Comment: Starting quests for Yes Man won't lock you out of anything else. There is a point of no return much later, but the game warns you about it and saves before it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Good ending" is a matter of opinion, particularly when dealing with complex and occasionally irreconcilable factions of New Vegas and especially when considering the independent ending. Personally I think House or NCR are better for Vegas.

If you roleplay as a good character and do the quests in a good way, you'll usually get an ending you like.

I'm only going to cover the quests that are required, that always appear as an ending slide, or you've specifically mentioned. If you can ignore something without it appearing as an end slide, I won't mention it. A full list of endings can be found [here](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout%3A_New_Vegas_endings).

Here's your to do list:

- Use the platinum chip to upgrade the securitrons
- Repair Rhonda at Black Mountain (you can instead kill Tabitha- either is better than just freeing Raul)
- Complete Raul's quest, Old School Ghoul. Pick whichever choice you prefer.
- Don't destroy the Brotherhood of Steel bunker
- Kill all the fiend leaders. Sucks to be them but they're raiders.
- Do not stop Lily taking her medication
- Ease tensions between the NCR and Kings by completing GI Blues and Kings Gambit diplomatically
- Get Rex a new brain
- Complete Flags of our Foul Ups by training the Misfits
- Complete Come Fly With me by helping Jason Bright
- Convince Boone to make amends over Bitter Springs
- Deal with the Powder Gangers in Vault 19

Comment: I don't like House, and NCR is cool, I guess. I do hate the Legion, so I never side with them